# how to connect device with ios 8.2 with xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone

hello I am working on iPhone app.I just updated my phone to newest iOS version (8.2) and now I have in Xcode (6.1.1) my device under Ineligible devices. . Now i am face a problem " Xcode does't support iOS 8.2 ". so now how i can resolve this problem.

Comment: You need to upgrade to Xcode 6.2

Comment: how to upgrade Xcode.I don't know how can i do it

Comment: Just open the App Store app on your Mac and then go to Updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should upgrade Xcode version 6.2

Answer (score 0):

i store sends you the updates for Xcode also, upgrade your Xcode to version 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your iPhone or upgrade Xcode to the newest version.

Comment: can u tell me how to Downgrade my iPhone device.Please tell me

Comment: try this: chttp://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/how-downgrade-from-ios-8-ios-7-reinstall-ios-8-3522302/

Comment: In other words it doesn't work anymore, but you can still upgrade Xcode in the app store under updates.